# Applying Function to an empty Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with columns / series df['Salary']. I need to Apply the following function to a new and empty series df['PercentageSalary'].

```
def applyPercentage(PercentageSalary):
     SumSalary=df['Salary'].sum()
     for num in df['Salary']:
          df['PercentageSalary']=(num/SumSalary)*100
    return num
```

I have used the above function in my data frame

```
df['PercentageSalary'].apply(applyPercentage)
```

But I do not get any data in my series df['PercentageSalary']

Comment: can you include a small sample of your data?